How To Support Range Requests In ServiceStack For application/json
The ServiceStack docs say that "HTTP Partial Content Support is added in true ServiceStack-style where it's now automatically and transparently enabled for any existing services returning" and then it then lists the 5 content types supported:-
https://docs.servicestack.net/service-return-types#partial-content-support
I have a service returning application/json and, as expected, adding a range http header to a request to the existing service made no difference to the response i.e. the range header seemed to be ignored and the full response was generated.
Is it possible to make the partial content functionality in ServiceStack work with application/json?

Did you return the JSON Response in a HttpResult as per the Partial Content Support docs:
return new HttpResult(json, MimeTypes.Json);


ah no I didn't change any code, I thought it wasn't necessary because of the "automatically and transparently" bit in the docs. my return statement is just a return of my response DTO and I let ServiceStack do the json serialisation etc magic. apologies, I am not too knowledgeable in how ServiceStack works so I have always just returned DTO's from my Get methods.

The rest of that sentence from the docs mentions the 5 different HttpResult examples which support Partial content, I've included the relevant one to use for returning JSON. If you want to serialize a DTO you can just call responseDto.ToJson() ext method.

ok cool I will try that out first thing tomorrow, fingers crossed it is that simple :) I am guessing it won't make any difference that I will return an HttpResult from the Get method instead of the DTO because in the end, it is still just json on the wire?

@danrockcoll It would limit the API to just returning JSON instead of any of the other supported Content Types. In which case you may only want to return serialize JSON for partial range requests, e.g. return Request.GetHeader(HttpHeaders.AcceptRanges) != null ? new HttpResult(dto.ToJson(), MimeTypes.Json) : dto;

actually i only want to return json anyway so that's a good thing :) ok so i made the change and i still ended up with a 200 return, but this time i saw the accept ranges header in the response so that was definitely better! then i realised it must be failing because i have compression on - i commented the compression attribute out and yep, then the range worked and i got a 206 partial content response with the expected snippet of json. so does that mean compression and partial content are mutually exclusive functionalities?

Yeah they're incompatible, compression compresses full responses.

ah well, ok maybe i can remove the compression attribute and use your conditional above to compress all responses (using code if that's possible) except for requests with a range header and return those uncompressed. does that sound ok or a bit convoluted? i don't want to break any http standards, but it feels a bit dodgy to have an endpoint sometimes return compressed data and sometimes not.

Sounds fine, not sure why it's dodgy, HTTP Requests/Responses are sent/received in isolation with features like compression being transparently handled by clients per request, whether other HTTP APIs use different HTTP features shouldn't be relevant.

hehe it's prob not actually dodgy, just me with my lack of knowledge thinking that! ok cool, i will give that a go, many thanks for all your help :)

apologies, i have one more question - i looked through the compression doc and couldn't see how to do the compression in code plus google searches just return lots of hits saying to use the compression attribute. is there a code equivalent of the compression attribute?

Can you open new questions for different questions please. You can access the different compression providers with the StreamCompressors static class. Although if this is for a new .NET project you may want to use ASP.NET Core's built-in Response Compression support.

yep will do, thanks mythz :)
